# Clojure : Return value being evaluated

Tags: clojure, classcastexception

**Simple question : Why does this function throw an exception when evaluated ?  **

- In the case where there is a duplicate in the string , there is a Class cast exception thrown upon finding the duplicate.
- In the case where the string has no duplicates, a NullPointerException is thrown.

**The Code **

```
(defn first-duplicate-char [str-in]
      (loop [list-Rem (seq str-in) set-Seen (set [])]
        (print (type list-Rem) " " list-Rem (next list-Rem) "\n")
        (if (= 0 (count str-in))
            nil
            (if (some #(= (first list-Rem) %) set-Seen)
                (first list-Rem)
                (recur  
                    (seq (next list-Rem))
                    (conj set-Seen (first list-Rem)))))))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that `(= 0 (count str-in))` never changes, so you eventually try to call `first` on `nil`. [**EDIT:** I'm wrong, your code actually works as is -- that if statement is just a no-op. I hope you enjoy the rest of this answer anyway.]

Instead, you should be calling `next` (not `rest`) on `list-Rem` in the `recur` and using `list-Rem` directly in the `if` test, using the property of `next` that returns nil for an empty seq. Here's how I would rewrite your code:

```
(defn first-duplicate [in]
  (loop [seen #{}
         remain (seq in)]
    (when-let [[head & tail] remain]
      (if (contains? seen head)
        head
        (recur (conj seen head) tail)))))
```

Changes:

- lowercasing names
- no need to call `seq` on the output of `next` or `rest`
- with sets, `contains?` (check for existence of key) is faster than `some` (run a predicate on elements until something yields a truthy value)
- set literal
- using `when` to return `nil` on test failure
- using `when-let` to destructure and bind first char and rest

Stylistic changes:

- names changed to be less specific (not restricted to strings, for instance)
- change order of loop locals so that recur looks more like structural recursion
- put loop locals on separate lines

Comment: this is the best possible answer to a somewhat odd question.  The problem was ultimately that I was enclosing the function call in another closure at the repl, due to some other issues.   I agree Its definetly better to use the when-let construct .

Comment: I like the eventual function written here, but the advice about rest/next is the worst you could give, so it's lucky the function uses neither rest nor next. Next is the function that returns nil; rest will return an empty seq (which is truthy).

Comment: Augh, thanks amalloy. I shouldn't be allowed to talk about rest and next without running examples through the REPL first. I get those reversed about half the time...